# Split() doesn't work properly

Tags: vb.net, string

well I'm doing a computing assessment and well I've ran into an issue with splitting a string. For some reason when the string splits the array stores the whole thing in Variable(0). The error that occurs is when it tries to assign TicketID(Index) a value, it says that the array is out of bound.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub ReadInformation(ByRef TicketID() As String, CustomerID() As String, PurchaseMethod() As Char, NumberOfTickets() As Integer, FileName As String)

    Dim Line, TextArray(3) As String
    Dim Index As Integer

    FileOpen(1, FileName, OpenMode.Input)

    For Index = 0 To 499

        Input(1, Line)
        TextArray = Line.Split(",")

        CustomerID(Index) = TextArray(0)
        TicketID(Index) = TextArray(1)
        NumberOfTickets(Index) = TextArray(2)
        PurchaseMethod(Index) = TextArray(3)

        MessageBox.Show(CustomerID(Index))

    Next

    FileClose()

End Sub
```

Here's the first 10 lines of the TextFile I'm trying to read:

```
C001,F3,10,S
C002,F3,2,O
C003,F3,3,S
C004,W2,9,S
C005,T3,10,S
C006,F3,2,S
C007,W1,3,O
C008,W3,1,O
C009,T2,2,S
C010,F2,9,O
```

Here's the Error Message I receive:

[Error Message](http://prntscr.com/cfdsm7)

Comment: if there are no commas in the string, then you get an array of one.  what does the data look like?

Comment: Could be that the first line is blank, first line lacks commas (e.g. is a header record of some kind), or perhaps the file is not encoded in a compatible format (e.g. ASCII vs. UNICODE)

Comment: I'll update the post with some text from the file I'm trying to read from.
The first line has data, and also has commas separating the text.

Comment: You should also include the actual error message you're receiving.

Comment: Do yourself a favour. Remove these legacy methods from VB6 era and use the more updated methods available in the NET Framework

Comment: By the way, in your code thare are 5 arrays at work. What if the array with insufficient space is one of those passed as parameters to this method? Are all arrays declared to have 500 elements? And what if the file has less than 500 lines to read?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean Steve. The Code I've shown is a procedure in the program, and I declared the original variables to hold 500 items. Also with the more updated methods is that with using StreamReader? The file has 500 Lines in it and each line is formatted the same way.

Comment: Do yourself a second favor and instead of parallel arrays, use a class and a collection for the data.  A third favor might be to not reinvent the wheel and use a CSV parser.

Comment: I've been taught to use this method of reading from Textfiles in school and I'm still quite new to VB.net (as in I'm just a novice).

Comment: What is the value of `Index` when you get the error?  That will show which line in the file is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use some Lists instead of arrays. In this way you don't have to worry about length of the arrays or if there are fewer lines than 500. Of course, using the more advanced NET Framework methods of the File.IO namespace is a must

```
Private Sub ReadInformation(TicketID As List(Of String), _
                            CustomerID As List(Of String), _
                            PurchaseMethod As List(Of Char), _
                            NumberOfTickets As List(Of Integer), _
                            FileName As String)

    for each line in File.ReadLines(FileName)
        Dim TextArray = Line.Split(","c)
        if TextArray.Length > 3 Then
            CustomerID.Add(TextArray(0))
            TicketID.Add(TextArray(1))
            ' This line works just because you have Option Strict Off
            ' It should be changed as soon as possible
            NumberOfTickets.Add(TextArray(2))
            PurchaseMethod.Add(TextArray(3)) 
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

You can call this version of your code declaring the 4 lists

```
Dim TicketID = New List(Of String)()
Dim CustomerID = New List(Of String)()
Dim PurchaseMethod = New List(Of Char)()
Dim NumberOfTickets = New List(Of Integer)()
ReadInformation(TicketID, CustomerID, PurchaseMethod, NumberOfTickets, FileName)
```

Another approach more Object Oriented is to create a class that represent a line of your data. Inside the loop you create instances of that class and add the instance to a single List

```
Public Class CustomerData
     Public Property TicketID As String
     Public Property CustomerID As String
     Public Property NumberOfTickets As Integer
     Public Property PurchaseMethod As Char
End Class
```

Now the loop becomes

```
Private Function ReadInformation(FileName As String) as List(Of CustomerData)

    Dim custData = New List(Of CustomerData)()
    For Each line in File.ReadLines(FileName)
        Dim TextArray = Line.Split(","c)
        if TextArray.Length > 3 Then
            Dim data = new CustomerData()
            data.CustomerID = TextArray(0)
            data.TicketID = TextArray(1)
            data.NumberOfTickets = TextArray(2)
            data.PurchaseMethod = TextArray(3)
            custData.Add(data)
        End If
    Next
    return custData
End Function
```

This version requires the declaration of just one list

You can call this version of your code passing just the filename and receiving the result fo the function

```
Dim customers = ReadInformation(FileName)
For Each cust in customers
    Console.WriteLine(cust.CustomerID)
    ...
Next
```

Or use it as an array

```
Dim theFirstCustomer = customers[0]
Console.WriteLine(theFirstCustomer.CustomerID)
```

Comment: NumberOfTickets.Add(TextArray(2)) gives me an error. 'Add is not a member of 'List(Of Integer)()'.

Also what do I change here to suit the newer code:

`Call ReadInformation(TicketID, CustomerID, PurchaseMethod, NumberOfTickets, FileName)`

Comment: That's odd. It is a List as the others so the Add method exists. Probably there is some error before

Comment: The program is using passing parameters (if that helps).
Also, I don't fully understand your second solution. As I've not been taught to use Classes yet in VB.NET. Also for the NumberOfTickets could I just use a string then convert said string into a integer?

Comment: Yes, you can use a string and convert. What I want to warn you is the fact that using Option Strict Off the conversion is executed automatically by the VB.NET compiler. With integers is relatively safe, but with other datatypes like decimals or dates the conversion can be really wrong. Better start to use Option Strict On at the project level

Comment: With the updated code I still get an error with the 'Dim NumberOfTickets = New List(Of Integer)()' The error I get is _Value of type 'List(Of Integer)' cannot be converted to 'List(Of Integer)()'_

Comment: I am sorry but that line cannot be the cause of the error. I can't see your whole code before that declaration but I think that is something before that line

Comment: Can I message you the full code? And/or the Source?

Comment: You can put the full/relevant code on a file sharing site like GDrive, OneDrive, Dropbox and then post the link here

Comment: Okay here's the code (dropbox): https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bqe6ymj0pnngat/Choral%20Sheilds.txt?dl=0

Comment: The code you have uploaded contains the second version of the ReadInformation method and you try to call it passing the parameters required by the first version.

Comment: also you pass Lists to CalculateDate that still wants arrays

Comment: Ehh, what do you mean?

Comment: I've cleaned up the code a bit: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bqe6ymj0pnngat/Choral%20Sheilds.txt?dl=0 I removed the code that done nothing to make it easier to read. Well, this is embarrassing lol. I noticed after re-reading your solution that I mixed the two together.

Comment: You should decide which version of ReadInformation you want to use in your code. The version with 5 parameters or the version with 1 parameter? Actually you have added the version with 1 parameter but you call it passing 5 parameters. This would not compile at all. Also inside the ReadInformation you have a block of code that calls recusively ReadInformation. That block is an example of the call remove it

Comment: I just tried again, I got this error http://prntscr.com/cfeawe with this code.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bqe6ymj0pnngat/Choral%20Sheilds.txt?dl=0

Comment: Declare NumberOfTickets to be of type String inside the CustomerData class. Apparently you have Option Strict set to On and this produces the error when you try to assign a string to an integer (It is irrilevant if the string contains only digits)

Comment: How do I turn off the Option Strict? Also the data it should be reading is only numbers no letters. I'll try what you said.
IT WORKED! Thanks so much. Heres the output(well some of it): http://prntscr.com/cfede0

Comment: I am curious to know why the downvote. This is not very fair. At least explain your reasons

Comment: I just have one more question, how would I use this and add up. For PurchaseMethod I can use a count occurence algorithm. But with Number  OfTickets, how would I work that out? As they're strings. Should I convert to String and if so how do I do it.

Comment: The downvote was an accident. How do I change it?
I clicked upvote but it went to -1 for some reason. When I click upvote it doesn't fix it.

Comment: @LukeHolland Now I think you should post a new question. This is enough long as it is now. And if you can't remove the downvote, do not worry, it is important that the answer works for you. Goodnight

Comment: sorry about the downvote. But thank you so much for the solution it really helps, plus I learn more! Also thanks for being understanding!